# How to get the correct reference to this item?

Tags: nodes

I'm writing a hook for a form but do not get the correct reference. What do I wrong?

```
  if($form_id == "entityqueue_subqueue_edit_form") {
    foreach ($form[eq_taxonomy_term][und][items] as $row => $rowinfo) {

      dpm($rowinfo[target_id]);
      if ($rowinfo[target_id][value] == 94){

        unset ($form[eq_taxonomy_term][und][items][$row]);
      }
    }
  }
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct reference is:

```
  if ($rowinfo['target_id']['#value'] == 94)
```